# Angular new tab navigation

Tags: angular, service, dom-events, angular2-changedetection, ng-template

I have created two components and a service being used by both of them. I want one component to be rendered by default and from within that component a link that will open the other component on new tab without changing the url (no routing).

one.component.html
<ng-template #one>

```
This is the default component and contains the link to open another component in a seperate tab but with same url.
<a (click)="openNewTab()"></a>
```

one.component.ts

```
// xyz code
window.open('/', '_blank').focus()
```

two.component.html

```
<ng-template #two>
This should be opened in a seperate tab 
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to pass full URL path of your second component, into your
`window.open('/', '_blank').focus()` method.

- Currently you're just passing single `/` that means it won't redirect to the specific path of your second component.
- Try changing URL like this, `window.open('localhost:4000/secondURL', '_blank').focus()`

Where `secondURL` is URL of your second component.

Comment: I want the url to be same as the one whose link is trying to open the second component which is localhost:4200 only that's why '/'

Comment: Okay Basically you want same URL but different component ?

Comment: Yes, same URL but different component in different tab while the first one to keep displaying in that tab only